# How to prove uniform convergence of series of functions $f_n(x) = x^n$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that the series of functions $f_n(x) = x^n$ converges to zero on x = $[0,1)$ (without using limits)?

I know I must solve for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, but when I try to do this I cannot seem to get an $N$ which depends only on $\epsilon$. I can only seem to solve it such that n must be greater than $N = log_x(\epsilon)$, which depends also on $x$ and carries with it the issue of log base zero.

Comment: Are you convinced that this sequence converges uniformly?

Comment: This: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234535/uniform-convergence-of-xn-on-1-1

Comment: "converges to zero"  means the limit is $0$, so what exactly do you mean by "without using limits"?