# Clarification on Pointwise and Uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

If a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to some function$f$, it doesn't imply uniform convergence but the converse is true.

My question is if we want to test the uniform convergence of a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ can we adopt the following proecdure:

Step1: Figure out the pointwise convergence of the sequence of functions, say $f_{n}$ converges to $f$.

Step2: Then find the integral of $f_{n}$ as well as integral of $f$. If the integrals are equal, then $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Is this a legit test? I am sure this is correct but I just want to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f_n:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$, $f_n(x)=x^n$, then $f_n$ converge pointwise to $f(x)\equiv 0$. Moreover we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-1}^1f_n(x)dx=0$$

However, $f_n$ does not converge uniformly, the proof can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234535/uniform-convergence-of-xn-on-1-1)

To determine whether the convergence is uniform, usually it is easy with the following criterion: suppose $f_n:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of functions which converges point wise to a function $f$, then the convergence is uniform if and only if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. This means my steps are not correct

Comment: Yes, I understand. This is because integration will be equal if sequence of functions is uniformly convergent and not vice-versa

Comment: Exactly, uniform convergence implies the convergence of integral, but not the other way(even with the point wise convergence)

Comment: We both pointed to the same thing. I got confused because of this, please take a look at the first answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615399/is-f-nx-n2x1-x2n-uniformly-convergent-on-0-1

Comment: This is like a counter positive of the result, because if the integral does not converge(to the integral of $f$) then the convergence cannot be uniform

Comment: But in light of the discussion we had, do you think it's correct?

Comment: I mean if you do not know about uniform convergence, then how can you test for it by calculating the integral of pointwise limit?

Comment: That's right. The point is, if the integral of $f_n$ converges to the integral of $f$, then we don't know whether the convergence is uniform; but if not, then the convergence is definitely not uniform. So testing the integral might give us some information of the convergence type, but also could be inconclusive.

Comment: Did you mean definitely not uniform?

Comment: Yeah, I mean not uniform, I've just fixed it.